# dynamically add properties to a dynamic type then use this type

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'd like to create a program to collate a variable amount of properties on an unknown object at run-time. Let me explain in more detail.
If I had an object called 'Object1' looking something like this...

```
public class Object1()
{
    public unknownType1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public unknownType2 Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have another object called 'Object2' that looks something like this...

```
public class Object2()
{
    public unknownType1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public unknownType3 Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to collate these objects dynamically at run-time to create something like this ...

```
public class Object3()
{
    public unknownType1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public unknownType2 Property2 { get; set; }
    public unknownType3 Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Notice, that both objects share the same Property1. 
I've already looked into ExpandoObject, however as I have no idea what type the objects or properties will be at compile time I didn't think that would work as Exapando infers the types. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to approach this?

Comment: So what would you do if both objects had a `Property1` whose types were not equal? Is that an error, or should `Property1` itself be `dynamic` or `object`? What about methods on the objects? You could derive from `DynamicObject` and implement your own logic, but it seems to me like you'd be much simpler off with an old-fashioned `Dictionary<string, object>`, seeing as how everything is dynamic anyway.

Comment: Think of this as a full outer join between object1 and object2 to create a list of object3's where there are matching property1's. These unknown object types will only carry data, similar to entities or data objects. For the purpose of this example I'm only interested in the properties. Other methods or values will be ignored. These objects and property types will be loaded through assembly references and then instances created dynamically. Does this answer your question?

Comment: By "matching `Property1`s", do you mean that you know for sure `Object1` and `Object2` use the same type for both their `Property1`s? In SQL parlance, an `OUTER JOIN` would produce *two* `Property1` columns, one for each object, and you'd have to alias these if you wanted to access them both -- unless you literally mean something like `WHERE Object1.Property1 = Object2.Property1`.

Comment: Would it simplify it if you think of it like this?

    SELECT Object1.Property1
        , Object2.Property2
        , Object2.Property3
      FROM Object1
      FULL JOIN Object2
        ON Object1.Property1 = Object2.Property1

Does this help?

Comment: Could you explain why a `Dictionary` doesn't do what you want (that is, why the existing answers don't help you)? The resulting object is, by definition, completely dynamic and of unknown composition, so it's hard to see how client code would even use it other than in the most generic way possible (as a bag of items). Maybe you should take this problem from the abstract to the concrete -- are you solving an actual problem or just trying to do something neat?

Comment: Why don't you use the decorator pattern for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Dictionary<string, object>` where 'Key' is Property name ('Property1', 'Property2', ...) and 'Value' is Property value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to collect properties and values of your any objects somethong like this:

```
object[] objectsCollection = new object[] { new StringBuilder(), new ASCIIEncoding() };
        foreach(var o in objectsCollection)
        {
            foreach(PropertyInfo pi in o.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string propertyName = ((MemberInfo)pi).Name;
                var propVal = pi.GetValue(o);
                //here you can collect properties and values
            }
        }
```

After you could collect your property names and values you could save it in some collection like Dictionary for example

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've gotten so far is anonymous types. if you do something like this...

```
 var Object1s = new List<Object1>() { Object1 };
 var Object2s = new List<Object2>() { Object2 };

 var object3s = Object1s
     .Join(Object2s, o1 => o1.Property1, o2 => o2.Property1,
         (o1, o2) => new
         {
             Property1 = o1.Property1,
             Property2 = o1.Property2,
             Property3 = o2.Property3
         }
     ).First();
```

...it produces an anonymous type that has all three properties. While the output of this can only be assigned to object, if a type with the prerequisite properties can be provided then the new statement can be changed to account for the type.

This isn't exactly generic as the properties are all specified, however you could change the new to look like this...

```
         (o1, o2) => new { o1, o2 }
```

... which would provide all the properties duplicated regardless and object3 would have to be called like this ...

```
object3.o1.Property1,
object3.o1.Property2,
object3.o2.Property3 ...
```

While not ideal, this will also work. Once I got my head into these anonymous types, my imagination filled with all sorts of possibilities. I could go on but I think you get the gist...